# Adding JQuery to Static Pages in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'd like to create a Static Page using this JQuery Slider that I found:

http://nicinabox.com/superslides/

I'm familiar with the concept of Enqueues but how can I select a specific page in my functions.php file to apply the script to?

I am using MAMP so I won't be able to provide a link to my website.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if(is_page('name of your page')){
  wp_enqueue_script('specific script');
}
else {
//.....
}
```

Comment: I'm doing that in my functions.php file but there is nothing in my splash.php (the template file I will use for my static page). The read me says that I should just add this: $('#slides').superslides() though I don't know where

Comment: add it to the footer.php file inside a <script></script> tag